# How to concatenate string literals in javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following expression,

```
var exp = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]' + getMinMax() + '$');
```

My `getMinMax()` function returns the value dynamically ex {2,5} , etc!

But it returns an exception, it says that syntax error in regular expression.
How can i correct it?

```
function getMinMax() {
   var minLength = Rule.MinimumLength,maxLength = Rule.MaximumLengh;
   var limitExpression = (minLength != 'undefined' && minLength != null ) ? minLength.toString() : '';

   limitExpression = (maxLength != 'undefined' && maxLength != null ) ? (limitExpression != '' && limitExpression != null) ? ('{' + limitExpression + ',' + maxLength.toString() + '}') : ('{' + maxLength.toString() + '}') : '';

   return limitExpression;
}
```

Comment: It works just fine, are you sure `getMinMax()` returns the string `"{2,5}"`?

Comment: i am dynamically getting the minlength and maxlength from the database and assign it throught getMaxMin() but it throws an exception?

Comment: Show us your getMinMax function… What do you mean by "database" - that sounds like an async task?

Comment: Set a breakpoint. Check the return value of `getMinMax()`. I guarantee you it is something other than `{x, y}`.

Comment: function getMinMax() {
            var minLength = Rule.MinimumLength,maxLength = Rule.MaximumLengh;
            var limitExpression = (minLength != 'undefined' && minLength != null ) ? minLength.toString() : '';
            limitExpression = (maxLength != 'undefined' && maxLength != null ) ? (limitExpression != '' && limitExpression != null) ? ('{' + limitExpression + ',' + maxLength.toString() + '}') : ('{' + maxLength.toString() + '}') : '';
            return limitExpression;
        }

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code (formatted) there.

Comment: I think not nesting ternary operators would be a good start. I have no idea what that does and no inclination to try and work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/9gfZp/) just fine.

My bet is that you have a small *typo* in your `Rule` object, so instead of `Rule.MaximumLengh`, you should probably have `Rule.MaximumLength`.

Also, as a *suggestion*, don't use so many chained ternary operators, it was really hard to read them.

Comment: For some definition of "works", I suppose. With just a minimum it returns a blank string instead of `{x,}`, and just a maximum it returns `{x}` instead of `{0,x}`. I agree it shouldn't result in a regex parse error though.

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
function getMinMax() {
   var minLength = Rule.MinimumLength,
       maxLength = Rule.MaximumLength,
       limitExpression = "";

       if (minLength != 'undefined' && minLength != null ) {
         limitExpression += minLength.toString();
       }
       if (maxLength != 'undefined' && maxLength != null ) {
         if (limitExpression.length>0) limitExpression+=",";
         limitExpression += maxLength.toString();
       }

   return limitExpression.length>0?"{"+limitExpression+"}":"";
}
```